# How can I sum up two ZoneOffset's?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, timezone-offset, zoneddatetime

I have two objects of [ZoneOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)'s parsed from Strings. How can I sum them up and apply to [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)?

For example:
 
original ZonedDateTime is `2017-12-27T18:30:00`, first offset is `+03`, second offset is `+05`

How can I get the output of `2017-12-28T18:30:00+08:00` or `2017-12-28T10:30:00`?

Comment: That does not make any logical sense, does it? Adding up zones seems incorrect, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have data array with offsets refer not to GMT+0, I have to process it somehow.

Comment: Still, that makes no sense. The only reasonable thing is to *convert* dates between timezone. But +03 +05 resulting in +08 is lacking any meaning.

Comment: "I have to process it somehow" doesn't clarify the requirement, though.  Because, among other things, 5 + 3 is not 11; so is that a typo, or is there some way we should understand your requirements so that we know what to do to get 11 out of those inputs?

Comment: Yes, I need to convert dates that already have offset to another parameterized timezone.

Comment: @Mark, thats typo, sorry.

Comment: Please show some code. What exactly is your input, what exactly is the expected output and for what reason?

Comment: "2017-12-27T18:30:00" is not a `ZonedDateTime`-representation (lacking the offset). Please try to rewrite your example code for sake of more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question this way (please check if correct): You’ve got one `ZonedDateTime` with a usual offset from UTC. I will call it `dateTimeWithBaseOffset`. And you’ve got another `ZonedDateTime` with an offset relative to the offset of the former `ZonedDateTime`. This is really incorrect; the designers of the class decided that the offset is from UTC, but someone used it differently from the intended. I will call the latter `dateTimeWithOffsetFromBase`.

Best of course if you can fix the code that produced `dateTimeWithOffsetFromBase` with the unorthodox offset. I am assuming that for now this will not be a solution you can use. So you need to correct the incorrect offset into an offset from UTC.

It’s not bad:

```
    ZoneOffset baseOffset = dateTimeWithBaseOffset.getOffset();
    ZoneOffset additionalOffset = dateTimeWithOffsetFromBase.getOffset();
    ZoneOffset correctedOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(baseOffset.getTotalSeconds()
            + additionalOffset.getTotalSeconds());

    OffsetDateTime correctedDateTime = dateTimeWithOffsetFromBase.toOffsetDateTime()
            .withOffsetSameLocal(correctedOffset);
    System.out.println(correctedDateTime);
```

Using your sample date-times this prints

```
2017-12-28T18:30+08:00
```

If you want the time at UTC:

```
    correctedDateTime = correctedDateTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(correctedDateTime);
```

This prints the datetime you asked for:

```
2017-12-28T10:30Z
```

For a date-time with an offset, we don’t need to use `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` will do and may communicate better to the reader what we’re up to (`ZonedDateTime` works too, though).